# git - After removing a remote, its branches are still reported

Tags: git, git-remote

I ran `git remote remove origin;`, and after that, `git log --all --decorate;` shows several branches from `origin`, such as `origin/master`, `origin/devel`, etc.

These are not local branches.

I've used `git remote prune origin` and `git remote update --prune`, but nothing changes. The first command prunes local tracking branches, so I don't expect it to help. The second command says "prune all the remotes that are updated.", and `origin` wasn't actually updated; perhaps this is why it's not pruning that repo?

How do I make git forget about this repository completely?

Comment: Does `git remote -v` list `origin`?

Comment: Also show the output of `git show-ref`.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this now, and it's not happening. `git remote remove origin;` is having the desired effect such that `git log --all --decorate;` doesn't show the remote branches.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with the git client, but perhaps what you're wanting is

```
cd .git;
rm -rf origin;
cd refs/remotes;
rm -rf origin;
```

This will get rid of all those branch names in `git log --all --decorate;` but I'm not sure if it's safe.

Answer (score -1):

To see what's going on with your remotes, use the `git remote -v` command.  It will produce something like:

```
$ git remote -v
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (fetch)
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (push)
cho45     https://github.com/cho45/grit (fetch)
cho45     https://github.com/cho45/grit (push)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (fetch)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (push)
```

Say you wanted to remove the REMOTE cho45 repo, do the following:

```
$ git remote rm cho45
```

Then confirm it:

```
$ git remote -v
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (fetch)
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (push)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (fetch)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (push)
```

If you want your LOCAL git to forget that REMOTE repo, then you can use the following process. BUT, it will toast that repo, be really sure you want that.

```
cd cho45/.git
rm -rf origin
cd refs/remotes
rm -rf origin
```

Comment: That's right, and that's what I see. I'm more concerned with the output of git log --all --decorate; I see the branches from origin still in there. How do I make them go away?

Comment: In the local repo?

Comment: If you want your LOCAL git to forget that REMOTE repo, then @Limited's answer is the way to go.  BUT, it will toast that repo, be really sure you want that.

Comment: That's right. The local repo should have no knowledge of that remote. I would rather accept your answer than my own answer. Can you change your answer to reflect this so I can accept it? Thanks!